# In AWS, why do we keep RDS instance in Private subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, subnet, private-subnet

We need ID/PW to login and access RDS instance, then why do we keep it in Private subnet?
What's the harm in putting RDS in public subnet, as anyway the RDS instance is password protected?

Comment: You shouldn't allow inbound connections from the internet to *anything* that doesn't strictly need to provide such access. If you expose a database then you're open to brute-force password attempts as well as the consequences of any security vulnerabilities in the database software or its configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your network you generally want to keep as many resources as possible outside of public scope.

If you put your RDS instance in a public subnet this makes it possible for traffic to route over the public internet and connect to your RDS instance. Even if it is password protected this is one method of preventing access, however if you want to keep this database secure you should take as many steps as possible to minimise inbound traffic.

It is best practice to keep any resources you do not want the public internet to access in a private subnet, using either a VPN or Direct Connect to connect to this host. Alternatively you could use a bastion host although be aware that again would be a public host. In addition to increase the security ensure the RDS instance is internal only and has strict security groups.